# Where to place example data in python package?

Tags: python, installation

I'm setting up my first Python package, and I want to install it with some example data so that users can run the code straight off. In case it's relevant my package is on github and I'm using pip.

At the moment my example data is being installed with the rest of the package into site_packages/, by setting `include_package_data=True` in setup.py, and referencing the files I want to include in MANIFEST.in. However, while this makes sense to me for files used by the code as part of its processing, it doesn't seem especially appropriate for example data.

What is best/standard practice for deploying example data with a python package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your example data in the repository in `examples` folder next to your project sources and exclude it from package with `prune examples` in your manifest file.

There is actually no universal and standard advice for that. Do whatever suits your needs.

Comment: So the idea is that the example data is not actually deployed with my code, but users can download it if they want it? That works for me, though I was hoping there might be some sort of standard location for such data or something. Thanks.